# Hyperledger Fabric error at adding new org to channel

Tags: docker, networking, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm running Fabric test network v2.2. Everything was successfully set up. I'm now trying to add an extra organization to the network.

I've generated crypto materials, and the configuration update tx. I sign the transaction, Essentially, everything executed correctly, where the success message regarding the addition of a peer was obtained.

EDIT:

Although it seems that the peer0 from a new org (org5) was correctly added, the org5 logs show that:

```
2021-05-31 13:13:50.794 UTC [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 7b0 Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint 'orderer.example.com:7050': failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup orderer.example.com on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host" channel=mychannel
```

peer0.org1.example.com shows similarly that:

```
2021-05-31 13:13:06.802 UTC [gossip.gossip] func1 -> WARN 409 Deep probe of org5.example.com:11071 failed: context deadline exceeded
2021-05-31 13:13:06.802 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 40a Could not connect to Endpoint: org5.example.com:11071, InternalEndpoint: org5.example.com:11071, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Logs:

Orderer logs: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/bada1278a096e252060e3d117b3c5719

peer0.org1.example.com logs: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/d5b6af66a62a18d9572399274a0a6aa5

org5 logs: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/cddba91566e66ca45f5494dff43196a0

peer 5 docker-compose:
https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/b82a64d4122e103f06dd7e4b9bc9023c

Comment: try to edit /etc/hosts and add '127.0.0.1 org5.example.com' rather than 'localhost org5.example.com'

Comment: I think it should be peer0.org5.example.com rather than org5.example.com,if you set org5.example.com,you may get "tls bad certificate"

Comment: That helped, @LiXian. But I stil cannot connect the org5 peer to the ordered and other peers

2021-05-31 11:30:27.751 UTC [gossip.gossip] func1 -> WARN 159 Deep probe of org5.example.com:11071 failed: context deadline exceeded
2021-05-31 11:30:27.751 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 15a Could not connect to Endpoint: org5.example.com:11071, InternalEndpoint: org5.example.com:11071, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded

Comment: can you show me your peer0.org5.example.com yaml file ? I guess that was because  your  env or docker network are not correct.

Comment: @LiXian - that's very likely.
Compose: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/cd5c4dd8d5f31ee405e33b4ef499bfe3
Configtx: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/bb67142b380a7ba908dc4b4e0e23da61

Comment: I have modify your docker-compose file https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BdQmx2H8zv/ you can try to use this yaml to start your peer0.org5.example.com,you may encounter other errors,because I dont know your fabric network name is test or fabric_test,I guess that is because your peer0.org5 not join same network as your exist fabric network

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to come back to you, @LiXian. Unfortunately, I still have the same problem.

Comment: I've added the peer defintion of peer5 @LiXian

Comment: may be you peers of org5 are not connect same docker network as other peers

Comment: In practice this is defining the network flag at the docker compose file to the same network as the original peers, correct?

Comment: yes,you can execute `docker network ls ` show your docker networks

Comment: NETWORK ID NAME DRIVER SCOPE
c300673e2724 bridge bridge local
d21fc30eb801 cactusfabrictestnetwork_test bridge local
ffdf447be8ec fabric_test bridge local
0a05fa40e158 host host local
a2f36c32c48c none null local

there are two different networks, in fact

Comment: I guess that your orginal docker network is `cactusfabrictestnetwork_test`,and you origin fabric component has join this docker network,so your new peer(peer0.org5.example.com) should join this docker network(`cactusfabrictestnetwork_test`),then all these component  can find each other

Comment: then your peer0.org5.example.com docker-compose file should like this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G7MyWSCN6g/ and before you start your peer0.org5 container ,set `COMPSE_PROJECT_NAME=cactusfabrictestnetwork`,and your peer0.org5 will join network  `cactusfabrictestnetwork_test`,reference this https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: That helped. @LiXian could you please post an answer (so I can give you the bounty?)

Comment: I have add an answer,Glad to help you。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your orginal docker network is `cactusfabrictestnetwork_test`,and your origin fabric components has join this docker network,so your new peer(peer0.org5.example.com) should join this docker network(cactusfabrictestnetwork_test),then all these component can find each other.

then your peer0.org5.example.com docker-compose file should like this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G7MyWSCN6g/ and before you start your peer0.org5 container ,set `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=cactusfabrictestnetwork`,and your peer0.org5 will join network `cactusfabrictestnetwork_test`,reference this https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/